# ElementTree better way to search out nodes (XPATH) using AND and 'parent'

Tags: python, xml, xpath, elementtree

I need to find tag=ITEM that match 2 criteria, and then get the parent tag=NODE@name based on this find.

Two issues:

1. I can't find a way for XPath to do an 'and', for example

   ```
   item = node.findall('./ITEM[@name="toppas_type" and @value="output file list"]')
   ```
2. Getting the parent NODE info without having to explicitely search and save it in advance of finding the ITEM, for example something like

   ```
   parent_name = item.parent.attrib['name']
   ```

This is the code I have now:

```
node_names = []
for node in tree.findall('NODE[@name="vertices"]/NODE'): 
    for item in node.findall('./ITEM[@name="toppas_type"]'):
        if item.attrib['name'] == 'toppas_type' and item.attrib['value'] == 'output file list':
            node_names.append(node.attrib['name'])
```

...to parse a file like this (snippet only) ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<PARAMETERS version="1.6.2" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://open-ms.sourceforge.net/schemas/Param_1_6_2.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <NODE name="vertices" description="">   
        <NODE name="23" description="">
          <ITEM name="recycle_output" value="false" type="string" description="" required="false" advanced="false" />
          <ITEM name="toppas_type" value="tool" type="string" description="" required="false" advanced="false" />
          <ITEM name="tool_name" value="FileConverter" type="string" description="" required="false" advanced="false" />
          <ITEM name="tool_type" value="" type="string" description="" required="false" advanced="false" />
          <ITEM name="x_pos" value="-620" type="double" description="" required="false" advanced="false" />
          <ITEM name="y_pos" value="-1380" type="double" description="" required="false" advanced="false" />
        </NODE>

        <NODE name="24" description="">
          <ITEM name="recycle_output" value="false" type="string" description="" required="false" advanced="false" />
          <ITEM name="toppas_type" value="output file list" type="string" description="" required="false" advanced="false" />
          <ITEM name="x_pos" value="-440" type="double" description="" required="false" advanced="false" />
          <ITEM name="y_pos" value="-1480" type="double" description="" required="false" advanced="false" />
          <ITEM name="output_folder_name" value="" type="string" description="" required="false" advanced="false" />
        </NODE>

        <NODE name="33" description="">
          <ITEM name="recycle_output" value="false" type="string" description="" required="false" advanced="false" />
          <ITEM name="toppas_type" value="merger" type="string" description="" required="false" advanced="false" />
          <ITEM name="x_pos" value="-620" type="double" description="" required="false" advanced="false" />
          <ITEM name="y_pos" value="-1540" type="double" description="" required="false" advanced="false" />
          <ITEM name="round_based" value="false" type="string" description="" required="false" advanced="false" />
        </NODE>
    <!--(snip)-->
    </NODE>
</PARAMETERS>
```

**UPDATE:**

@Mathias Müller

Great suggestion - unfortunately when I try to load the XML file, I get an error. I'm not familiar with lxml...so I'm not sure if I'm using it right.

```
from lxml import etree
root = etree.DTD("/Users/mikes/Documents/Eclipseworkspace/Bioproximity/Assay-Workflows-Mikes/protein_lfq/protein_lfq-1.1.2.toppas")
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "src/lxml/dtd.pxi", line 294, in lxml.etree.DTD.__init__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:187024)
lxml.etree.DTDParseError: Content error in the external subset, line 2, column 1
```

Unfortunately, ElementTree will not accept that xpath in its tree.find(xpath) or tree.findall(xpath)

Comment: Please show clearly what you would like the output to be, given exactly the input document you included here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you do not need nested loops at all, a single XPath expression would suffice. I am not exactly sure what you would like the final result to be, but here is an example with `lxml`:

```
>>> import lxml.etree
>>> s = '''<NODE name="vertices" description="">
...
...     <NODE name="23" description="">
...       <ITEM name="recycle_output" value="false" type="string" description="" required="false" advanced="false" />
...       <ITEM name="toppas_type" value="tool" type="string" description="" required="false" advanced="false" />
...       <ITEM name="tool_name" value="FileConverter" type="string" description="" required="false" advanced="false" />
...       <ITEM name="tool_type" value="" type="string" description="" required="false" advanced="false" />
...       <ITEM name="x_pos" value="-620" type="double" description="" required="false" advanced="false" />
...       <ITEM name="y_pos" value="-1380" type="double" description="" required="false" advanced="false" />
...     </NODE>
...
...     <NODE name="24" description="">
...       <ITEM name="recycle_output" value="false" type="string" description="" required="false" advanced="false" />
...       <ITEM name="toppas_type" value="output file list" type="string" description="" required="false" advanced="false" />
...       <ITEM name="x_pos" value="-440" type="double" description="" required="false" advanced="false" />
...       <ITEM name="y_pos" value="-1480" type="double" description="" required="false" advanced="false" />
...       <ITEM name="output_folder_name" value="" type="string" description="" required="false" advanced="false" />
...     </NODE>
...
...     <NODE name="33" description="">
...       <ITEM name="recycle_output" value="false" type="string" description="" required="false" advanced="false" />
...       <ITEM name="toppas_type" value="merger" type="string" description="" required="false" advanced="false" />
...       <ITEM name="x_pos" value="-620" type="double" description="" required="false" advanced="false" />
...       <ITEM name="y_pos" value="-1540" type="double" description="" required="false" advanced="false" />
...       <ITEM name="round_based" value="false" type="string" description="" required="false" advanced="false" />
...     </NODE>
... <!--(snip)-->
... </NODE>'''
>>> root = lxml.etree.fromstring(s)
>>> root.xpath('/NODE[@name="vertices"]/NODE/ITEM[@name = "toppas_type" and @value = "output file list"]')
[<Element ITEM at 0x102b5f788>]
```

And if you actually need the name of the parent element, you can move to the parent node with `..`:

```
>>> root.xpath('/NODE[@name="vertices"]/NODE/ITEM[@name = "toppas_type" and @value = "output file list"]/../@name')
['24']
```

**Parsing an XML document from a file**

The function `etree.DTD` is the wrong choice if you would like to parse an XML document from a file. A DTD is not an XML document. Here is how you can do it with `lxml`:

```
>>> import lxml.etree
>>> root = lxml.etree.parse("example.xml")
>>> root
<lxml.etree._ElementTree object at 0x106593b00>
```

**Second Update**

If the outermost element is `PARAMETERS`, you need to search like this:

```
>>> root.xpath('/PARAMETERS/NODE[@name="vertices"]/NODE/ITEM[@name = "toppas_type" and @value = "output file list"]')
[<Element ITEM at 0x106593e18>]
```

Comment: Great suggestion - unfortunately when I try to load the XML file, I get an error. I'm not familliar with lxml...so I'm not sure if I'm suing it right.<br>root = etree.DTD("/Users/mikes/Documents/Eclipseworkspace/Bioproximity/Assay-Workflows-Mikes/protein_lfq/protein_lfq-1.1.2.toppas")
<br>Traceback (most recent call last):
<br>  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
<br>  File "src/lxml/dtd.pxi", line 294, in lxml.etree.DTD.__init__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:187024)
<br>lxml.etree.DTDParseError: Content error in the external subset, line 2, column 1

Comment: @BurningKrome The question made it seem like you are parsing an XML document. But `etree.DTD` suggests you are working with a _DTD_ (you did not mention this until now). Perhaps you need to update the question with what you are _actually_ trying to do, or open another question?

Comment: Sorry. It is an XML file. Honestly, Googling how to open the file came up with DTD (and not much else) :D

Comment: When I use parse, it comes up empty. I wasnt sure if I was loading it correctly.....>>> t = etree.parse("/Users/(snip)/protein_lfq-1.1.2.toppas")
>>> t 
<lxml.etree._ElementTree object at 0x10550a830>
>>> t.xpath('/NODE[@name="vertices"]/NODE/ITEM[@name = "toppas_type" and @value = "output file list"]/../@name')
[]

Comment: @BurningKrome Please do not add programming code in comments. I have updated my answer to show you how to parse XML from a file. If your result is empty, this is most likely because your _actual_ XML document has a namespace or because `NODE` is not really the outermost element. If you think that could be the case, show the first few lines of your _actual_ XML document in the question.

Comment: Updated. Also note, I need to get ALL the node names that match, not a specific one. The contents of the file will be unknown at the time of parsing.

Comment: P.s. I did try it with PARAMETERS as the outermost node...still with blank results.

Comment: @BurningKrome Unfortunately, you did not edit in what I was asking for (the beginning of the actual XML document). The path expression already finds _all_ occurrences of this type, but it is no use to keep me guessing any longer about the actual format.

Comment: I apologize if I made an error. I did paste in the start of the XML document. I cut and pasted from Visual Studio Code and placed it in the OP.

Comment: @BurningKrome My bad, sorry about that! The XML did not change much and I overlooked it initially. I edited the answer again, hopefully it works for you now.

Answer (score 1):

In XPath, everything inside `[]` are [*predicates*](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath20-20101214/#id-predicates) (filtering criteria), and are not restricted to attribute filtering.

Without any criteria, the XPath expression:

```
//NODE/@name
```

will produce all `name` attribute values of all `NODE` nodes.

In your case, you care only about the `NODE` nodes having specific children. So this means you have to filter the `NODE` nodes:

```
//NODE[‹predicate here›]/@name
```

Specifically, for `NODE` nodes having `item` nodes with the same criteria as per issue №1 of your question, the predicate would be:

```
ITEM[@name="toppas_type" and @value="output file list"]
```

i.e match direct `ITEM` children with specific values for their `name` and `value` attributes.

The full XPath would then be:

```
//NODE[ITEM[@name="toppas_type" and @value="output file list"]]/@name
```

Applying this with `lxml` to your sample XML in a Python REPL:

```
>>> doc.xpath('//NODE[ITEM[@name="toppas_type" and @value="output file list"]]/@name')
['24']
```